# ItemUpdated firing twice

Tags: 2007, event-handlers

I am adding custom meta-data to item that user uploaded

```
item["Title"] = "My Title";
item["Column1"] = "column1";
item.Update();
```

When I comment out the item.Update() then the itemUpdated event does not fire twice. How can I add additional custom meta-data (in addition to whatever else end user is adding from the 
front-end)? I have to use ItemUpdated event handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reasons for it firing twice can be several; one common is that your call to Update makes the receiver fire once again. Use the DisableEventFiring to prohibit the Update within your receiver to trigger another event.

Comment: Thank you Wictor. You have solved my hours of migrant. LOL.

To prevent for ever loop you can call DisableEventFiring() and then EnableEventFiring(). A Sample code:

public override void ItemUpdated(SPItemEventProperties properties)
        {
            //some handling here
            ListItem item = properties.ListItem;
            item["someproperty"] = "some value";
            this.DisableEventFiring();
            //save changes
            addedItem.Update();
            this.EnableEventFiring(); 
        }

THIS WORKS LIKE CHARM....

Comment: Please mark this post with answer as it has been resolved.

Comment: Remember to put the disable/enable code inside a try/finally, so that event firing is enabled if you encounter an exception

Comment: Ah and it is you that ask the question that can set it as answer

Comment: This item has been resolved. Mark it with complete status. Thanks